# IdentityServer Create and Revoke API Tokens

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, oauth-2.0, duende-identity-server

I have a asp.net core hosted blazor application using

```
builder.Services.AddIdentity<IdentityUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
    {
        // ...
    }
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
```

and

```
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<IdentityUser, ApplicationDbContext>()
```

I want to add a feature, that a user can create an api token with passing an (optional) expiration date, and name.
The created tokens should be revokable.
Ideally the tokens are limited to api endpoints.

Is ServerSideSessions the way to go?
Since IdentityServer is rotating keys, will it be capable of validating tokens that were issued +1 year ago?

The reason for this is, that we have monitoring systems, that monitor data coming from that api. these systems only can issue http calls, no oauth integration.

## EDIT

I found https://github.com/DuendeSoftware/Samples/blob/main/IdentityServer/v6/PAT/src/IdentityServer/Pages/PAT/Index.cshtml.cs

It seems like I can create Tokens with a Lifetime with Injecable ITokenService.

Still i didn't find a default way to revoke tokens.

Answer (score 1):

I think IdentityServer is not the right tool to handle API Tokens. What IdentityServer can handle is Oauth Clients and their secrets but that just allowed an oauth capable client to create a token that can be directly used on an API endpoint. Server side session just stores the user data on the server side not in a cookie so this is not the right option.

In my opinion the right way to handle that is to create a custom AuthenticationHandler maybe similar to this:
https://rmauro.dev/api-key-authentication-extending-the-native-implementation/

In there you can get access to a dbcontext for example where the API Tokens are stored and you can validate them.

You can then use AddPolicyScheme to switch between either the apiauthentication or your custom scheme.

https://code-maze.com/dotnet-multiple-authentication-schemes/

Probably something like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication( x=> x.DefaultScheme == "TOKEN_OR_JWT")
    .AddIdentityServerJwt()
    .AddScheme<YourCustomHandler>("YOUR-CUSTOM-SCHEME")
    .AddPolicyScheme("TOKEN_OR_JWT", "TOKEN_OR_JWT", options =>
    {
        // runs on each request
        options.ForwardDefaultSelector = context =>
        {
            // check if an API-TOKEN header is present
            string? apiToken = context.Request.Headers["API-TOKEN"];
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(apiToken))
                return "YOUR-CUSTOM-SCHEME";

            // otherwise always use the jwt scheme for identityserver
            return IdentityServerJwtConstants.IdentityServerJwtScheme;
        };
    });
```